# How to add dark mode in Nextjs 13.4.10?

Tags: next.js, darkmode

I am trying to add dark-light mode to my Nextjs app version 13.4.10 without using the next-theme package. First of all, if there is a selected mode in the cookie or storage, I want to use it, otherwise, I want to use the mode in the OS. I tried to do it both with hooks and using cookies, but I couldn't prevent focus. I looked at the documentation of tailwind https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode it says `On page load or when changing themes, best to add inline in head to avoid FOUC`. But in Next.js 13.4.10, you cannot add a script tag in the head tag because it throws an error. Then, I found this discussion https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/50772

```js
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} bg-zinc-50 dark:bg-zinc-900 text-zinc-900 dark:text-zinc-50`}>
       <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
            try {
              if (localStorage.getItem("theme") === 'dark' || (localStorage.getItem("theme") === null && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
                  document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')
              } else {
                  document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')
              }
            } catch (_) {}
          `,
        }}>
        </script>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

This works, but in the tailwind documentation says `add head tag`. We added to the body above. It just didn't feel right. Or is it right? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

I use this darkmode setup and all works well. It's ok with NextJS14 too. Install next-themes with npm, yarn or pnpm :

> pnpm add next-themes

Create file provider.tsx in the root of your app with this following code :

```js
"use client"

import * as React from "react"
import { ThemeProvider as NextThemesProvider } from "next-themes"
import { type ThemeProviderProps } from "next-themes/dist/types"

export function ThemeProvider({ children, ...props }: ThemeProviderProps) {
  return <NextThemesProvider {...props}>{children}</NextThemesProvider>
}
```

In your main layout.tsx (RootLayout) add the provider like this:

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from "@/components/theme-provider"

export default function RootLayout({ children }: RootLayoutProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
        <head />
        <body>
          <ThemeProvider
            attribute="class"
            defaultTheme="system"
            enableSystem
            disableTransitionOnChange
          >
            {children}
          </ThemeProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </>
  )
}
```

I've found it there: https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/dark-mode/next

Have fun !